# Getting errors with structs/linked lists

Tags: c, struct, types, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm getting the following errors:

> A1.c:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #inlcude
>    A1.c:29: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
>    A1.c: In function 'main':
>    A1.c:30: error: incompatible types in assignment
>    A1.c: In function 'insert':
>    A1.c:45: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
>   A1.c:54: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'

For the following code : (keep in mind that a lot of the variables for this are at the    moment not being used as its incomplete and needs much work, but I can't get it compile to test whether my code works or not, obviously it's not )

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 100           //max Last name field length
#define MAXR 100           //max Rest field length
#define MAXM 5             //max message-string length e.g., "FIND"
#define MAXI 520           //max input line length

typedef char Last_t[MAXL];
typedef char Rest_t[MAXR];

void insert(char last[],char rest[]);

//DEFFINITION OF OUR NODE or CONTACT
typedef struct NodeTag {
   Last_t     Last;
   Rest_t     Rest;
   struct NodeTag *Link;
} Node;

//DEFINITION OF CONTACT LIST
typedef struct {
   Node *Index[26];
   Node *L;
} ContactList;

//STATIC CONTACT LIST INITIATED
static ContactList con ;

int void main () {
con.Index= NULL;
con.L = NULL;
insert( "Amir", "S");


}

//create a node and insert it to the List con of ContactList
void insert ( char last[], char rest[]) {
 Node *node, *next, *prev;
 node= malloc (sizeof(Node));
 strcpy(node->Last,last);
 strcpy(node->Rest,rest);
 if (con.L == NULL ){
   node->Link=con.L;
   con.L = node ;
  printf("Added %s %s\n",last,rest);
  }

 else {
  Node *current = con.L ;

  while(current->Link !=NULL) {
     if (current->Link == NULL) {
           current->Link = node;
           printf("Added %s %s\n",last,rest);

     }
     current = current->Link;
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First line - It's #include NOT #inlcude

How can it be int void main() ? It should be either int or void.

con.Index = NULL is invalid. Index is a const pointer and NULL is a void *. Same reason you cannot do Index++. You cannot change the value of Index.

The warnings should vanish when you correct line 1.

All these are easily correctable if you read your code. Have you tried to do that ?